# Multiple marks on a path

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths, decorations, pgf-decorations

I want to add a multitude of marks to a single path. However, sometimes these marks are heavily misplaced. For example, the blue arrows should be a little bit ahead of the red ones.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates { (5*0.02109, 5*-0.12607)(5*0.2274, 5*-0.1806)(5*0.4037, 5*-0.02751)(5*0.536, 5*0.4091)(5*0.768, 5*0.2045)(5*0.7262, 5*-0.02055)(5*0.8538, 5*-0.1366) }
        [postaction={decorate}, decoration={markings,
            % Red arrows
            mark=between positions 0.1 and 0.9 step 0.25 with {\arrow[red, line width=1mm]{>};},
            % Blue arrows
            mark=between positions 0.2 and 0.9 step 0.25 with {\arrow[blue, line width=1mm]{>};}
        }]
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Have you tried adding a second `postaction`?  Any number are allowed, and they are executed in order.

Comment: Incidentally, the problem with the original code was that you were marking the path with marks out of order and this is Expressly Forbidden in the manual.  Splitting the decoration in two circumvents this restriction as in involves a double-pass on the path.

Comment: @AndrewStacey, I found it now that you mentioned it, page 328. It's a little hard to notice that sentence when you're just skimming the manual for the information you need.

Comment: I agree that it's an obscure detail and my comment was purely to ensure that the *explanation* is on this page somewhere as otherwise it's not clear to others why your original code doesn't work.  I think it's a good question and a neat solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ryan Reich's (thanks!) comment was the solution: multiple postactions. Note that every "decoration block" needs its own decorate postaction.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw plot[smooth, tension=.7] coordinates { (5*0.02109, 5*-0.12607)(5*0.2274, 5*-0.1806)(5*0.4037, 5*-0.02751)(5*0.536, 5*0.4091)(5*0.768, 5*0.2045)(5*0.7262, 5*-0.02055)(5*0.8538, 5*-0.1366) }
        [postaction={decorate, decoration={markings,
            % Red arrows
            mark=between positions 0.1 and 0.9 step 0.25 with {\arrow[red, line width=1mm]{>};}
        }}]
        [postaction={decorate, decoration={markings,
            % Blue arrows
            mark=between positions 0.2 and 0.9 step 0.25 with {\arrow[blue, line width=1mm]{>};}
        }}]
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]