# Naming the nodes of `nodes near coords` for later use

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

I would like to use `pgfplots` command `nodes near coords` to get a
list of named node (`(no1)`, `(no2)`, `(no3)` etc.) that I can use
afterwards to draw some paths that I fail to construct with `pgfplots`
only.

I suppose it would need to use `scatter/@post marker code` but I did
not understand very well that part of the manual (p. 82).
Actually, if `nodes near coords` is a redefinition of `scatter/@pre
marker code` so I suppose I don't really need `nodes near coords` and
could use a altered scatter.
I did not find however the code defining `nodes near cords` in the
manual and got lost into the huge code files of `pgfplots`.

Here is an example taken from the `pgfplots` manual that could
constitute a minimum example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[nodes near coords]
\addplot+[only marks] coordinates {
(0.5,0.2) (0.2,0.1) (0.7,0.6)
(0.35,0.4) (0.65,0.1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Unfortunately I just do not know if that is really part of the answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no inbuilt functionality for this, but you can add it yourself relatively easily by making use of the `\coordindex` macro that holds the index of the current coordinate:

```
\pgfplotsset{
    name nodes near coords/.style={
        every node near coord/.append style={
            name=#1-\coordindex,
            alias=#1-last,
        },
    },
    name nodes near coords/.default=coordnode
}
```

If you then add `name nodes near coords` to your `\addplot` options, the nodes will be named from `<node name>-1` to `<node name>-<max>`, with `<node name>` either specified using the optional argument or defaulting to `coordnode`. The last node for each plot will be named `<node name>-last`.

Here's an example of how this could be used:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{
    name nodes near coords/.style={
        every node near coord/.append style={
            name=#1-\coordindex,
            alias=#1-last,
        },
    },
    name nodes near coords/.default=coordnode
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    nodes near coords,
    ]
\addplot+[only marks,   name nodes near coords=myname] coordinates {
(0.5,0.2) (0.2,0.1) (0.7,0.6)
(0.35,0.4) (0.65,0.1)};
\addplot+[only marks,   name nodes near coords=secondname] coordinates {
(0.3,0.3) (0.2,0.2) (0.4,0.6)
(0.7,0.4) (0.6,0.1)};
\end{axis}
\draw (myname-0) -- (myname-last);
\draw (secondname-3) to [out=180, in=0] (secondname-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: very nice answer!

Comment: Note that `pgfplots` comes with some sort of "step node counter" on its own: you can substitute `name=#1-\thecoordnode` by `name=#1-\coordindex`.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: Ah yes, of course! Thanks for that! I've edited my answer.

Comment: Can one modify this to get the exact positions, so just the coordinates, instead of nodes?

Answer (score 2):

Just quickly, don't have time for a full MWE right now; but one can also use the `mark=text` plot style with `text mark as node=true`:

```
\addplot+[
  only marks,
  mark=text, 
  text mark={}, % empty for now; try also \coordindex
  text mark as node=true,
  text mark style={%
    name=MYNODE\coordindex,
    color=orange,
    shape=circle,
    draw,
    inner sep=0pt,
    minimum size=0pt,
    align=center,
    text width=5pt,
    text depth=0pt
  },
]
  table[
    x index=1, %x expr=\coordindex,
    y expr=0.0,
  ] \mytable ;
\end{axis}

\draw[thick,green] (0,0) -- (MYNODE1.center);
```

This will give you 5pt circles named MYNODE0, MYNODE1 etc that you can use afterwards. Note that if you do use some text for the node, then the size or the drawn node will change (but of course, you may not have to draw anything, in which case there should be no problem).

Comment: This worked quite nicely, as long as you don't forget to actually set `mark=text` ;). Thank you! (It also gives exact positions - which is nice)