# legend style customization in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I have this bar graph, and I want to do 3 things:

1. Remove the numbers in the bars, they are overlapping (If possible keep only one, symbolizing that both bars have the same value);
2. Within the frame of the legend, enter "Data Size" and then the values ​​of 10KB and 20KB;
3. Change the y-axis value to 28

The code I'm using:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
enlargelimits=0.3,
legend  style={at={(0.5 ,-0.20)},
anchor=north,legend  columns =-1},
ylabel ={Memory Usage (KB)},
xlabel ={Transmissions},
symbolic x coords ={10,100,250},
xtick=data,
nodes  near  coords ,
nodes  near  coords  align ={vertical},
]
\addplot  coordinates  {(10,25.4) (100,25.4) (250,25.4)};
\addplot  coordinates  {(10,25.4) (100,25.4) (250,25.4)};
\legend{10KB,20KB}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The graph I have is this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ymin = 0, ymax = 28,
    ybar,
    enlarge x limits=0.3,
    legend  style={at={(0.5 ,-0.20)},
    anchor=north,legend  columns =-1},
    ylabel ={Memory Usage (KB)},
    xlabel ={Transmissions},
    symbolic x coords ={10,100,250},
    xtick=data,    
    nodes  near  coords  align ={vertical},
  ]

  \addlegendimage{empty legend}
  \addplot[nodes  near  coords, fill = blue!30]  coordinates  {(10,25.4) (100,25.4) (250,25.4)};
  \addplot  coordinates  {(10,25.4) (100,25.4) (250,25.4)};

  \addlegendentry{Data Size}
  \addlegendentry{100KB}
  \addlegendentry{20KB}
  %\legend{10KB,20KB}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

1. Remove `nodes near coords`
2. Use `\addlegendentry{Data Size}`
3. Set the limit with `ymax`

[image]

Comment: But how can i display only one value in the bars? See the answer from @marmot.

Comment: @Mutante Add the option to just one of the plots `\addplot[nodes  near  coords, fill = blue!30]  coordinates  {(10,25.4) (100,25.4) (250,25.4)};`

Answer (score 2):

This is just a small addendum to caverac's nice answer that shows how one may merge two `nodes near coords` into one.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\newcounter{mynodeindex}
\pgfplotsset{%based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75811/121799
    step nodeindex/.code={\stepcounter{mynodeindex}},
    name nodes near coords/.style={
        every node near coord/.append style={/pgfplots/step nodeindex,
            name=#1-\themynodeindex,
            alias=#1-last,
        },
    },
    name nodes near coords/.default=coordnode
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
enlargelimits=0.3,
legend  style={at={(0.5 ,-0.20)},
anchor=north,legend  columns =-1},
ylabel ={Memory Usage (KB)},
xlabel ={Transmissions},
symbolic x coords ={10,100,250},
xtick=data,
nodes  near  coords={},
nodes  near  coords  align ={vertical},
name nodes near coords
]
\addplot  coordinates  {(10,28) (100,28) (250,28)};
\addplot  coordinates  {(10,28) (100,28) (250,28)};
\legend{10KB,20KB}
\end{axis}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Xmax}{\themynodeindex/2}
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(\X+\Xmax)}]  in {1,...,\Xmax}
{\path (coordnode-\X) -- (coordnode-\Y) node[midway,yshift=2pt] {28};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't know about `every node near coord`, nice! (+1)