# How do I combine a bar graph and line chart with pgfplots/tikz?

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I am trying to combine a bar graph and line chart into one figure. I plotted the mass of 5 different materials for 3 different thicknesses. Now, I also have temperature data for all 15 bars. For each material, I want to connect the three temperature data points in one line, preferably sloped. How do I connect each temperature value to the respective bar?

This is what I got so far. (for material 3 and 4, I only have one temperature value, so the "only marks" option is okay.)

[image: bar and line chart]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{anysize}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}   
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\pgfplotsset{width=14.5cm,
symbolic x coords={material1,material2,material3,material4,material5},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
ybar=11pt,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
ymin=0,ymax=1500,  
ylabel=material mass $\mathrm{[kg]}$, 
enlarge y limits=0.0,
enlarge x limits=0.15,
legend style={at={(1,-0.1)},draw=none}, 
legend columns=3,
x tick label style={text width=2.9cm,align=center},
xtick={data},
xtick align=inside,
minor y tick num=1,
height=0.37\linewidth,
bar width=0.5cm,
]
\addplot
[fill=black!30,draw=none] 
coordinates{
    (material1, 316.91)
    (material2,338.93)
    (material3,542.05)
    (material4,653.4)
    (material5,244.72)
};
\addplot
[fill=black!60,draw=none] 
coordinates{
    (material1,475.05)
    (material2,508.06)
    (material3,812.13 )
    (material4,979.44)
    (material5,366.83 )
};
\addplot
[fill=black!80,draw=none] 
coordinates{
    (material1,623.97)
    (material2,676.96)
    (material3,1084.65)
    (material4,1305.05)
    (material5,488.78)
};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}
[
ymin=0,ymax=600,
axis y line*=right,
ylabel=temperature $\mathrm{[K]}$, 
enlarge y limits=0.0, 
enlarge x limits=0.15, 
height=0.37\linewidth,
xticklabels=\empty
]
\addplot[very thick,draw=red!90]
coordinates{
    (material1, 387.04)
    (material1,274.51)
    (material1,211.07)
};
\addplot[mark=circle,very thick,draw=red!90]
coordinates{
    (material2,461.93)
    (material2,326.88)
    (material2,253.97)
};
\addplot[only marks,very thick,draw=red!90]
coordinates{
    (material3,530.84)};
\addplot[only marks,very thick,draw=red!90]
coordinates{
    (material4,484.68)};
\addplot[mark=circle,very thick,draw=red!90]
coordinates{
    (material5,515.55)
    (material5,350.43)
    (material5,268.02)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Do you get the output you show from the very code you posted here? If so, how do you compile this? (I am asking because when I compile your code with `pdflatex`, say, on an updated TeXLive2019 installation, I get an output in which the bars overlap.)

Comment: I forgot to include the anysize package.

Comment: Well, I believe I could answer this question, at least in principle. But after adding `anysize` there are `overfull hbox` warnings. It would be great if you could clean up your code to the extent that others have to only deal with the important issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the vertical lines, because when you don't use `ybar` there is no shift of coordinates. So the trick is to also use `ybar` in the second `axis` environment. But because you don't want to see/show them, we make them invisible and just store the coordinates by misusing the `nodes near coords` feature. Having them it is then simple to draw the lines and marks, respectively.

For details, please have a look at the comments in the code.
(Please note that I allowed myself to heavily simplify your code. I hope you agree that this is much more readable and thus maintainable.)

```latex
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.16,
        % create a custom style to store common `axis options`
        my axis style/.style={
            width=\linewidth,
            height=0.37\linewidth,
            ybar=5pt,       % <-- reduced so the bars don't overlap
            bar width=0.5cm,
            enlarge y limits=0.0,
            enlarge x limits=0.15,
            % to avoid to repeat the symbolic coords over and over again,
            % use them from a table ...
            xticklabels from table={\data}{material},
            % ... ensure that every data points get a corresponding xtick ...
            xtick={data},
            % ... and then just number the entries by the row index of the table
            table/x expr={\coordindex},
            xtick align=inside,
            minor y tick num=1,
        },
        % create a style to store the coordinates of the
        % temperature data
        Name/.style={
            % use the `nodes near coords` for that
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords style={
                % they shouldn't show any value ...
                coordinate,
                % but store coordinate labels which can later be used
                name=#1\coordindex,
            },
        },
    }
    % create a table of data
    % (which is much more clearly arranged than the "coordinates")
    % use any number that can clearly be distinguished from regular values to indicate
    % that you don't have any data here. In this case, I used -1.
    % (You can't use NaN here, because then no coordinate will be created and thus
    %  the (automatic) numbering of the named coordinates is working as expected.)
    \pgfplotstableread{
        material    d1      d2      d3      T1      T2      T3
        material1   316.91  475.05  623.97  387.04  274.51  211.07
        material2   338.93  508.06  676.96  461.93  326.88  253.97
        material3   542.05  812.13  1084.65 -1      530.84  -1
        material4   653.40  979.44  1305.05 -1      484.68  -1
        material5   244.72  366.83  488.78  515.55  350.43  268.02
    }{\data}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        % call the created style
        my axis style,
        % (list the remaining options)
        ymin=0,
        ymax=1500,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line*=left,
        ylabel=material mass $\mathrm{[kg]}$,
        % use a (custom) `cycle list` which is also much clearer than
        % providing the options to each `\addplot` command
        cycle list={
            {draw=none,fill=black!30},
            {draw=none,fill=black!60},
            {draw=none,fill=black!80},
        },
    ]
        % then this here is very simple
        % (and should be self-explanatory)
        \addplot table [y=d1] {\data};
        \addplot table [y=d2] {\data};
        \addplot table [y=d3] {\data};
    \end{axis}

    % here we also create a ybar plot, but don't draw the bars.
    % Instead, we just store named coordinates at the bar ends.
    \begin{axis}[
        my axis style,
        %
        ymin=0,
        ymax=600,
        axis y line*=right,
        ylabel=temperature $\mathrm{[K]}$,
        xticklabels=\empty,
        % make the bars invisible
        only marks,
    ]
        % use the custom `Name` style here to store the named coordinates
        \addplot [Name=a] table [y=T1] {\data};
        \addplot [Name=b] table [y=T2] {\data};
        \addplot [Name=c] table [y=T3] {\data};
    \end{axis}

    % the named coordinates can only be accessed after the `axis` environment.
    % Now simply draw the lines ...
    \foreach \i in {0,1,4} {
        \draw [very thick,red!90] (a\i) -- (b\i) -- (c\i);
    }

    % ... and marks
    \foreach \i in {2,3} {
        \fill [red!90] (b\i) circle [radius=2.5pt];
    }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 1):

I had to reset a few values of your settings to get a semi-reasonable output and no warnings. One possible way of gaining access to the vertical positions of the bars is to use `nodes near coords` with the auto-naming from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75811/121799). This allows one to reconstruct the plots.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}   
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\pgfplotsset{width=0.8\linewidth,
symbolic x coords={material1,material2,material3,material4,material5},
}
\pgfplotsset{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75811/121799
    name nodes near coords/.style={nodes near coords={},
        every node near coord/.append style={anchor=center,coordinate,
            name=#1-\coordindex,%/utils/exec=\typeout{#1-\coordindex},
            alias=#1-last,
        },
    },
    name nodes near coords/.default=coordnode
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
ybar=11pt,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
ymin=0,ymax=1500,  
ylabel=material mass $\mathrm{[kg]}$, 
enlarge y limits=0.0,
enlarge x limits=0.15,
legend style={at={(1,-0.1)},draw=none}, 
legend columns=3,
x tick label style={text width=2.9cm,align=center},
xtick={data},
xtick align=inside,
minor y tick num=1,
height=0.37\linewidth,
bar width=0.3cm,
]
\addplot
[fill=black!30,draw=none,name nodes near coords=m1] 
coordinates{
    (material1, 316.91)
    (material2,338.93)
    (material3,542.05)
    (material4,653.4)
    (material5,244.72)
};
\addplot
[fill=black!60,draw=none,name nodes near coords=m2] 
coordinates{
    (material1,475.05)
    (material2,508.06)
    (material3,812.13 )
    (material4,979.44)
    (material5,366.83 )
};
\addplot
[fill=black!80,draw=none,name nodes near coords=m3] 
coordinates{
    (material1,623.97)
    (material2,676.96)
    (material3,1084.65)
    (material4,1305.05)
    (material5,488.78)
};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}
[
ymin=0,ymax=600,
axis y line*=right,
ylabel=temperature $\mathrm{[K]}$, 
enlarge y limits=0.0, 
enlarge x limits=0.15, 
height=0.37\linewidth,
xticklabels=\empty
]
\addplot[very thick,draw=red!90,opacity=0,name nodes near coords=n1]
coordinates{
    (material1, 387.04)
    (material1,274.51)
    (material1,211.07)
};
\addplot[mark=circle,very thick,draw=red!90,opacity=0,name nodes near coords=n2]
coordinates{
    (material2,461.93)
    (material2,326.88)
    (material2,253.97)
};
\addplot[only marks,very thick,draw=red!90]
coordinates{
    (material3,530.84)};
\addplot[only marks,very thick,draw=red!90]
coordinates{
    (material4,484.68)};
\addplot[mark=circle,very thick,draw=red!90,opacity=0,name nodes near coords=n5]
coordinates{
    (material5,515.55)
    (material5,350.43)
    (material5,268.02)
};
\end{axis}
\draw[very thick,draw=red!90] plot[samples at={0,1,2}] 
(m\the\numexpr\x+1\relax-0|-n1-\x);
\draw[mark=*,very thick,draw=red!90]
     plot[samples at={0,1,2}] (m\the\numexpr\x+1\relax-1|-n2-\x);
\draw[mark=*,very thick,draw=red!90]
     plot[samples at={0,1,2}] (m\the\numexpr\x+1\relax-4|-n5-\x);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}2
```

[image]

This is a proof of principle. I did not really fix the overlapping bars because I really have no idea what output you are after. However, if you fix this in your code, this solution can be used. I am definitely not saying this is the most elegant solution possible.

Comment: +1 for releasing my headache for the naming of the `nodes near coords`. I all the time was trying something like `name=a-\plotnum-\coordindex` which didn't work, but I couldn't get this from the error message. Otherwise I think my solution is more elegant ;)