# Pgfplots: rotate arrow marks by a third arbitrary data

Tags: pgfplots

In the following mwe, my goal is to have the arrows point in the arbitrary direction given by the third column of the data.

[image: the mwe image]

After reading some answers (for example from Dr. Feursänger [there](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=24308) or [this other question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/z3lLXLPzQ5I)), I started to define my marker, with the hope to rotate it. I couldn't go any further. Is there a simple solution ?
The image is generated with:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
  5.30E-001 5.30E-001   -7.85E-001
  5.96E-001 5.89E-001   -7.85E-001
  6.69E-001 6.39E-001   -7.85E-001
  7.47E-001 6.81E-001   -7.85E-001
  8.29E-001 7.13E-001   -7.85E-001
  9.14E-001 7.36E-001   -7.84E-001
  1.00E+000 7.48E-001   -7.81E-001
  1.09E+000 7.49E-001   -7.72E-001
  1.18E+000 7.41E-001   -7.55E-001
  1.26E+000 7.22E-001   -7.28E-001
  1.35E+000 6.93E-001   -6.91E-001
  1.43E+000 6.54E-001   -6.43E-001
  1.50E+000 6.07E-001   -5.88E-001
  1.57E+000 5.51E-001   -5.25E-001
  1.63E+000 4.87E-001   -4.57E-001
  1.68E+000 4.17E-001   -3.85E-001
  1.73E+000 3.40E-001   -3.11E-001
  1.76E+000 2.60E-001   -2.34E-001
  1.79E+000 1.75E-001   -1.57E-001
  1.81E+000 8.82E-002   -7.85E-002
}\datatable

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
  \pgfdeclareplotmark{yawarrow}{%
    \draw[->] (0,0)--(0,100);
  }
  \begin{axis}
    [
      xlabel={$x$},
      ylabel={$y$},
    ]
    \addplot[%
      mark=yawarrow,
 %     mark options={rotate=\thisrowno{2}}, % This won't work
    black] table[x index={0},y index={1}] {\datatable};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Edit

Based on the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75155/arrow-heads-as-plot-marks), I've tried to update my code as follows. This fails with `Undefined control sequence \yaw`. Am I missing something on the use of the option and on of the `\yaw` ?

```
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\datatable} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rows}{\pgfplotsretval-2}

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left, trim axis right]
  \pgfdeclareplotmark{yawarrow}{%
    \draw[->] (0,0)--(0,100);
  }
  \begin{axis}
    [
      xlabel={$x$},
      ylabel={$y$},
    ]
      \foreach \k in {0,...,\rows}
      {
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\k}{[index]0}\of\datatable 
      \let\x\pgfplotsretval
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{\k}{[index]1}\of\datatable 
      \let\y\pgfplotsretval
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{\k}{[index]2}\of\datatable 
      \let\yaw\pgfplotsretval
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\K}{\k+1}
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{\K}{[index]0}\of\datatable 
      \let\X\pgfplotsretval
      \pgfplotstablegetelem{\K}{[index]1}\of\datatable 
      \let\Y\pgfplotsretval
      \addplot [
        mark=yawarrow,
        mark options={rotate=\yaw}, %Won't work either
      ] coordinates {(\x,\y) (\X,\Y)};
    }
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this using a quiver plot instead of rotating markers:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
  5.30E-001 5.30E-001   -7.85E-001
  5.96E-001 5.89E-001   -7.85E-001
  6.69E-001 6.39E-001   -7.85E-001
  7.47E-001 6.81E-001   -7.85E-001
  8.29E-001 7.13E-001   -7.85E-001
  9.14E-001 7.36E-001   -7.84E-001
  1.00E+000 7.48E-001   -7.81E-001
  1.09E+000 7.49E-001   -7.72E-001
  1.18E+000 7.41E-001   -7.55E-001
  1.26E+000 7.22E-001   -7.28E-001
  1.35E+000 6.93E-001   -6.91E-001
  1.43E+000 6.54E-001   -6.43E-001
  1.50E+000 6.07E-001   -5.88E-001
  1.57E+000 5.51E-001   -5.25E-001
  1.63E+000 4.87E-001   -4.57E-001
  1.68E+000 4.17E-001   -3.85E-001
  1.73E+000 3.40E-001   -3.11E-001
  1.76E+000 2.60E-001   -2.34E-001
  1.79E+000 1.75E-001   -1.57E-001
  1.81E+000 8.82E-002   -7.85E-002
\end{filecontents}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
      xlabel={$x$},
      ylabel={$y$},
    ]
    \addplot[quiver={
        u={sin(\thisrowno{2} r + 90)},
        v={cos(\thisrowno{2} r + 90)},
        scale arrows=0.1
    }, -latex] table[x index={0},y index={1}] {data.dat};
    \addplot [thick] table {data.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As far I can guess, the quiver marks can be changed to other marks and this solution is applicable to other problems. Should I give another title to my question to reflect the approach of your answer ?

Comment: @Vser: The quivers can be changed to use other arrow heads, but you can't easily use general plot marks (rotated squares without arrow lines, say). But I think this would still apply to most use cases. Yes, it would probably be good to rename this question so people actually needing a way to rotate plot marks (as opposed to needing a way to draw rotated arrows) won't be disappointed.

Comment: I've tried to reflect your (accurate) comment in the title. I hope it's understandable.